# What's the purpose in being able to resize a form for iOS?

Tags: ios, delphi, resize, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

When designing a form for a Firemonkey iOS application, you're able to resize the form into any possible size, and even the debug shows it as so. Obviously, iOS devices have very particular screen sizes. Why is it made possible to make my form in any dimensions I want?

[image]

I haven't gotten to the point of running this on any iOS device yet. This is my very first trial building an iOS HD application using Firemonkey. It's just very peculiar why it would let me design the form to any size I wish, since iOS apps are always full-screen and aligned to fit within various device screens.

Comment: Are forms *necessarily* full-screen? Does Firemonkey *necessarily* know it's running on iOS?

Comment: Well the entire application / project is based on iOS. It's specifically an iOS application. I haven't gotten to the point of using it on any iOS device yet, but I would think it would always run in full-screen.

Comment: @RobKennedy This is my very first trial in any Firemonkey application. I started one a while back when I first got XE2 but was only a very general overview, and didn't get deep at all. Now, this is the first time I'm really looking into building any Firemonkey app at all, and am designing my first iOS trial app.

Comment: Well, there are different form sizes for iPad/iPhone/iPhone5. Horizontal/vertical mode. Aren't there templates for a specific device when you create the form? At least there are in XE4/XE5.

Comment: @LURD When I created new applications, no, there's no wizard or anything to customize it for a specific device. It just gets straight into raw design.

Comment: In XE4/5 the form adjusts its size automatically when displayed on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all iOS devices run on the same resolution.
The iPhone 5 has a different aspect ratio than the iPhone 4.
And the iPad 3 has double the resolution of my iPhone 4.

You may also show a form covering only part of the screen (arguably more useful on an iPad).

Remember that FireMonkey is not written for iOS alone, it also covers OSX. In OSX you'd want all the normal VCL/Windows rules to apply.
Still I can see the sense if you're building a email application of having multiple screens (i.e. frames/panels/etc) performing different functions.
You can also imagine a pulldown/popup (modeless please) that does searching.
If you implement that using a different form it should not be full-screen.

So yes I can see lots of uses for non-fullscreen forms in iOS.

[image]

These two panels could be implemented using 2 forms; resizing would be useful here.

Comment: I can see how forms can be encapsulated from within the main form. But what I don't understand is how it allows you to change the "main form" size any way desired. I guess it doesn't matter in the end, as long as I align everything properly, it will make no difference.